# NHibernate ISet of Value Objects error in production NULL values in DELETE Statement on fields that have value

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a error in production that is built with 2 web servers against a common SQL-server database.

I have one root entity with a ISet of Value Objects.

The mapping looks like this.

```
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.DayInfos)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Table("WeeklyMailDayInfo")
            .Component(c =>
                           {
                               c.Map(x => x.DayOfWeek);
                               c.Map(x => x.ImageText);
                               c.Map(x => x.ImageUrl);
                           });
```

When the user changes a ImageUrl the code simply removes and adds a new DayInfo to the ISet.

The problem I see in production is from the logfiles generated by NHibernate.
The log indicates
DELETE FROM WeeklyMailDayInfo WHERE WeeklyMailFk = @p0 AND DayOfWeek = @p1 AND ImageText = @p2 AND ImageUrl = @p3;@p0 = 3003, @p1 = 'Tuesday', @p2 = NULL, @p3 = NULL

Note the 2 nulls even though there is a value in ImageUrl and ImageText already.

I'm unable to reproduce this in any unittest or in my development enironment.

DevWeb and unittests are executed against SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're mapping a list of components, NHibernate has no primary key to uniquely identify the row. It therefore has to perform the DELETE based on equality with all columns as you indicate.

As for the NULLs, have you tried running your test suite against a copy of production? Are you certain that you don't have any DayInfo objects in the collection with no ImageText and ImageUrl?

Comment: Yes I understand that the DELETE needed. Hmm, could it be that somehow duplicates have been introduced. That might be the case, will have to look into that tomorrow. Odd though that I never see the duplicates when rendering the page.

Comment: Somehow duplicates was present. Changed the code to deal with that seems to work as expected after that change.